# Calculate the expectation of the function of a random variable

Tags: probability

Calculate the following expectation $$E[a^{X}]$$ where $X\sim B(n,p)$ is a binomial random variable and ***a*** is a positive constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) we get
$$
E[a^X]=\sum_{k=0}^n a^k \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(ap)^k(1-p)^{n-k}=(ap+1-p)^n,
$$
where we in the last equality used [the binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).